# Search query dynamically using postgres, nodejs and html

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql

I have created a node.js app and connected to the Postgres database successfully. I also created a .html file with a form that contains an input text field and a submit button.

When I enter something into the text field and press submit button, I want my node.js app to search that record using the entered input text field of the form and display it on the browser.

I've tried using request parameters and fetched the records successfully, but this does not require the use of HTML. I  want it to fetch dynamically with the help of a button.

I've also tried calling the dynamic URI(like "/abc/:xyz") using onclick() on the submit button but didn't get any result.

### node.js[end point that handles the "get" request]

```
app.get('/details/:regn_no', (req, res, next) => {

      const regn_no = req.params.regn_no;

      const results = [];

      pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {

        if(err) {
          done();
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
        }

        const query = client.query('select * from vt_owner where regn_no= 
             $1',[regn_no]);

        query.on('row', (row) => {
          results.push(row);
        });
        query.on('end', () => {
          done();
          return res.json(results);

        });
      });
    });
```

### index.html [contains a simple html form]

````
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
     shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>GET OWNER DETAILS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
<form id="form">
<div class="form-group" id="formID" >
<label for="regn_no">REGN_NO</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserInput" placeholder="Enter 
regn_no here" name="regn_no"><br>
<input type="button" 
onclick="location.href='http://localhost:3000/details" id="submitButton"  
value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>      
</div>
</body>
</html>


```jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#form").submit(function (event) {
          $.post('/details', $("#form").serialize(), function (data) {
            console.log(data) //data is the response from the backend
          });
          event.preventDefault();
        });
 })
````

When i type "regn_no" and click submit. The app should fetch the records matching that specific "regn_no" and display them.

Comment: Are you using jquery for ajax request?

Comment: I tried using jquery but that didn't help:(

Comment: Please paste your jquery code above. So, that we can check where is the mistake.

Comment: just did it..please take a look at it !

Comment: Please check my answer and flow the steps. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things you have to correct.

1) Convert your button to Submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

2) Changes your Jquery code like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/details/'+$('#UserInput').val(),
            method: 'get',
            success : function(data) {
                   // 1) manipulate your result (data) if required
                   // 2) display result inside specfic div eg.   
                  $('#div_id').html(data);
                   console.log(data)
            }
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: tried your solution but got no response..what i want exactly is on clicking the submit button..the value of the text field should be passed to a variable in my nodejs end point so that i can add that to my search query dynamically and get the result

Comment: the browser console shows "Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function"

Comment: The answer has been updated. Do you have knowledge of ajax or not?

Comment: No ,but i can try to learn it if it solves my issue...can you give me a referrence code for that?

Comment: thank you so much...your solution did solve my problem :)

Comment: Please upvote if this solves your problem. It might help to others as well.

Comment: did it, the post score is recorded but not updated as my reputation currently is below 15

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Lose the form entirely, it's not needed here. A simple text input and button with an onclick handler. Call your endpoint using jQuery and update a div with the results you receive. Something like the following:

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="jqueryInput">
  <button id="jqueryButton">Search</button>

  <div id="jqueryOutput"></div>

  <script>

    $("jqueryButton").click(function() {
      $.post("demo_test.asp", { regn_no: $("jqueryButton").val() }, function(res, status) {
        $( "#jqueryOutput" ).html( res );
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tweak the URL and the way the parameters are passed to fit your API. Good luck.

Comment: i tried it..when i click the button , no response is being triggered

Comment: what i want exactly is on clicking the submit button..the value of the text field should  be passed to a variable in my nodejs end point so that i can add that to my search query dynamically and get the result